# digital signature display issue - TCPDF

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

When I generate a digital signature using the TCPDF library, it is successfully generated. When viewed using Adobe Acrobat Reader, the approved digital signature appearance is displayed. However, the signature does not appear in the signature appearance.

Code -

```
    PDF::setSignature($certificate, $certificate_key, $password, '', 3,$info,'A');
    PDF::AddPage();
    $html = view('tcpdf');
    
    PDF::writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
    PDF::SetFont('helvetica', '', 6);

    PDF::setSignatureAppearance($x, $y, $w, $h);
    
    PDF::Output(public_path('digital-signed-pdf'.time().'.pdf'), 'I');
    PDF::reset();
```

How to generate signature image text with verified sign.

Comment: If the digital signature is being successfully generated but not appearing in the signature appearance, you may want to ensure that you are providing the correct parameters to the `setSignatureAppearance` method.

Comment: In setSignatureAppearance(82,120,40,20) set. When we set blank box generated. When we click on this box valid signature popup show. But in the box signature image not show. If need any other value let me know